# Two databases are shown when only one is created in Android using SQLite databases

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sqlite

This question has been asked just out of curiosity!! I have implemented a database `DB1` on android. But when I call method `this.databaselist` in main activity I am shown that two databases exist `DB1` and `DB-journal`. Why is second database created by android automatically? Do we need to take care of these journal databse too while working on multiple databases??

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633274/  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046596/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manner in which SQLite uses temporary files is not considered part of the contract that SQLite makes with applications.

A **journal** is a temporary file used to implement atomic commit and rollback capabilities in SQLite. The journal is always located in the same directory as the database file and has the same name as the database file except with the 8 characters **"-journal"** appended.

The journal is usually created when a transaction is first started and is usually deleted when a transaction commits or rolls back. The journal file is essential for implementing the atomic commit and rollback capabilities of SQLite. Without a journal, SQLite would be unable to rollback an incomplete transaction, and if a crash or power loss occurred in the middle of a transaction the entire database would likely go corrupt without a rollback journal.

**The journal is usually created and destroyed at the start and end of a transaction, respectively.** But there are exceptions to this rule.

If a crash or power loss occurs in the middle of a transaction, then the journal file is left on disk. The next time another application attempts to open the database file, it notices the presence of the abandoned rollback journal (we call it a "hot journal" in this circumstance) and uses the information in the journal to restore the database to its state prior to the start of the incomplete transaction. This is how SQLite implements atomic commit.

If an application puts SQLite in exclusive locking mode using the pragma:

```
   PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;
```

For more details [Check](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can elect to keep the journal in memory so that no -journal file is created:

```
pragma journal_mode=memory;
```

Note that you need to run this each time you open the database.

credit goes here: [How to disable Android SQLite Journal file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046596/android-sqlite-journal-how-to-disable)