# How to turn off journaling sqlite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Read other posts in SO, but accepted answers does not work. So here is it again:

How to turn off journaling and so can export DB from emulator? This is how I try to deal with it:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("db6", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE",null); // <-- has no effect, neither with OFF
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item(_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR);");
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046786/1979882 have you tried this? I can recommend to use a database from resource files where this option has been activated already.

Comment: Why do you care about the journal file when you want to export?

Comment: 50 question is not enough if I am in the flow .. sorry

Comment: @János did you find how to do this. I'm trying the same for prepping my database.