# cursor.moveToNext() taking long time?

Tags: android, optimization, android-sqlite

When fatching large no. of records in android sqlite using `Cursor.movetoNext()`
taking more time in *Android* **compare** to *IOS* platform.
Is there any way to reduce the time of `Cursor.movetoNext()` or use something else

**I used Cursor resultSet = super.executeSqlAndGetResultSet(sql);**

```
 public Cursor executeSqlAndGetResultSet(String sql) throws Exception{
       DatabaseOps db = DatabaseOps.defaultDatabase();
       Cursor resultSet = db.executeQuery(sql, null); 
       return resultSet;
}
```

Using **cursor.movetoNext()** taking long time as compare to IOS in Android

```
while(cursor.movetoNext()){  
//block to iterate column value of database table.
}
```

Comment: could you share your work?

Comment: Not in comment. Edit your question

Comment: If you are seeing white screen, then you are obviously running the query on the main thread. That is a No-No. You should be using a `CursorLoader` or a `AsyncQueryHandler`, to load. It will be quicker and give your app more responsiveness.

Comment: we have 5000+ rows in table and one more thing we used multiple table joins.

Comment: we are not iterating 5000 rows in while loop this 5000 rows in database and query will iterate on the basis of primary id of table but when i execute that query in sqlite it will taking 40ms and on android cursor.movetonext taking 2000ms(2sec)

Comment: but once my cursor object filled with Database record i wanna iterate one by one to get record until my cursor don't have any record.

Comment: with the help of that iteration i made my custom class object list which is used in showing list element.

Comment: can you please send me any demo code or poc ??

Comment: Thanks pskink  for the given example link

Comment: Try **indexing** your WHERE and your JOIN fields. It can speed up things up to 400 times faster (empyrically tested).

Comment: – Bernoulli Gate, we already applied indexing on join columns. But thanks for suggestion

Comment: And did you apply them on the WHERE fields, as well?

Comment: yes @BernoulliGate

Comment: You mean to say that every call to `movetonext` is taking 2 seconds? You mist have something really wrong in your DB or code! You will have to post your database setup and your SQL.

Comment: no its taking time only for very first record

Comment: So, it seems like it takes its time to rebuild the cache every time.

Comment: @BernoulliGate, i don't know.

Comment: Maybe, keeping the journal in memory will speed up things a bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046596/how-to-disable-android-sqlite-journal-file

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to display data with fast database execution so you can go with custom [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). I hope this approach will help.

Please refer 
[Using custom simpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708971/using-custom-simplecursoradapter)

Comment: no need for a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` - you can just use it without overriding anything

Comment: @pskink, actually i need custom cusor Adapter because i wanna perform lots of operation in my chat module with this i.e. showing date (today, tommorow) etc.

Comment: @ManjeetSinghGoyal no, you can use `ViewBinder` for that